# Закидание данных в json с html

Tags: javascript, база-данных, json, typescript, angular

Есть корзина, в которой есть две части, первая- товары (products), вторая - форма с input, после нажатия на кнопку, с формы считываются данные в json отлично, а вот товары не добавляются (назвал немного криво - user - это данные, что введены с инпутов). Скину на всякий случай почти весь код корзины, код именно с считыванием данных находится внизу кода (с приставкой orders). Дали совет, что можно попробовать так как ниже, но не получается.

```
data = {
  userData: UserData,
  products: Array<Product>
}
```

Буду очень благодарен за подсказки и помощь.

basket.components.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BasketService } from 'src/app/core/services/basket/basket.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { UserInterface } from 'src/app/core/interfaces/user/user.interface';
import { ProductInterface } from 'src/app/core/interfaces';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-basket',
  templateUrl: './basket.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./basket.component.css']
})
export class BasketComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() user: UserInterface;
  @Output() newOrder = new EventEmitter<UserInterface>();
  @Output() update = new EventEmitter<UserInterface>();

  basketList;
  product = [];
  basket;
  productIndex: number;
  id: number;
  userList: Array<UserInterface>;
  productList: Array<ProductInterface>;

  private unsubscribe = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private basketService: BasketService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getBasketList();
    this.getOrders();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe.next();
    this.unsubscribe.complete();
  }

  clearBasket(): void {
    localStorage.clear()
    this.product = []
  }

  getBasketList(): void {
    this.basketService.basket.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.product = data;
      }),
      error => {
        console.log(error)
      };
  }

  deleteBasketItem(productId: number) {
    this.basketService.removeFromLocalstorage(productId);

    var index = this.product.findIndex(x => x.id == productId);
    this.product.splice(index, 1);
  }

  submit(user: UserInterface): void {}

  getOrders(): void {
    this.basketService.getOrders()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.userList = data
      }),
      error => console.log(error)
  };

  // getOrderItem(): void {
  //   this.basketService.getOrderItem()
  //     .subscribe(data => {
  //       this.productList = data
  //     }),
  //     error => console.log(error)
  // }

  updateOrders(user: UserInterface): void {
    this.basketService.updateOrders(user)
    .subscribe();
  }

  addOrder(user: UserInterface): void {
    this.basketService.addOrder(user)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.getOrders();
        // this.getOrderItem();
      });
  }

  //get total(){
  //  return this.product.reduce((sum,x) =>
  //  ({count: 1,
  //    price:sum.price+x.count*x.price}),
  //    {quantity: 1, price: 0}).price;
  //}
}
```

basket.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserInterface } from 'src/app/core/interfaces/user/user.interface';
import { ProductInterface } from '../../interfaces';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class BasketService {
  url = 'http://localhost:3000';

  basket = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  basketCount = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  product = [];
  basketService: any;
  userId: number;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.setToLocalStorage();
  }

  setToBasket(product): void {
    this.setToLocalStorage(product);
    console.log(product);
  }

  removeFromLocalstorage(id) {
    var basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basket"));
    var index = basket.findIndex(x => x.id == id);

    basket.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify(basket));
  }

  private setToLocalStorage(product?): void {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("basket")) {
      localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify([]));
    } else {
      this.basket.next(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basket")));
      this.basketCount.next(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basket")).length);
    }
    if (!product) {
      return
    }

    const basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("basket"));
    basket.push(product);
    localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify(basket));
    this.basket.next(basket);
    this.basketCount.next(basket.length);
  }

  getOrders(): Observable<Array<UserInterface>> {
    return this.http.get<Array<UserInterface>>(`${this.url}/orders`);
  }

  // getOrderItem(): Observable<Array<ProductInterface>> {
  //   return this.http.get<Array<ProductInterface>>(`${this.url}/orders`);
  // }

  updateOrders(user: UserInterface) {
    return this.http.put<Array<UserInterface>>(`${this.url}/orders`, user);
  }

  addOrder(user: UserInterface) {
    return this.http.post<Array<UserInterface>>(`${this.url}/orders`, user);
  }

}
```

basket.component.html

```
...
            <app-user-order class="user-order"
                            (update)="updateOrders($event)"
                            (newUser)="addOrder($event)">

            </app-user-order>
```

в json передается обьект:

```
"orders": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "firstName": "Иван",
      "secondName": "Иванов",
      "surname": "",
      "city": "Львов",
      "postNumber": "123",
      "phone": "0999999999",
      "addItionalInfo": ""
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

добавил в basket.component строку - user.product = this.product;

```
addOrder(user: UserInterface): void {
    user.product = this.product;
    this.basketService.addOrder(user)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.getOrder();
      });
  }
```

и добавил в user.interface

```
export class UserInterface {
    .............
    product: any;
}
```